# How to handle API to retry the call on error

Tags: javascript, api, rest, google-api

I am making `POST` calls to GA API. I have an array of objects I want to send to the API, I am looping trough the array and within each iteration I make one the first request following another request on promise fullfilment of the first one:

```
propertyArr.forEach((e, i, a)=>{
            gapi.client.request({ 
                path: 'https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties', 
                method: 'POST', 
                body: e
            })
            .then(e=>{
                gapi.client.request({
                    path: 'https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/' + e.result.name + '/dataStreams',
                    body: dataStreamArr[i],
                    method: 'POST'
                })
            })
        })
```

It however happens very often that the request ends with `429` error. What is the correct way of handling this and retrying the request on such error?

[GAPI request function reference](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md#----gapiclientrequestargs--)

Answer (score 0):

According to Mozilla, normally they usually send back a `Retry-After: 3600` seconds header. Thought this is not always true.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

Sometimes the message body contains info about what happened, for example:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 429,
        "message": "Quota Error: Number of recent failed reporting API requests is too high, please implement exponential back off.\nSee developer documentation for details at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis_request_errors",
        "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
    }
}
```

Not sure about current quotas. I found a post when they write this:
[image]

https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/60281574/google-analytics-reporting-api-429-error-but-only-before-noon-12-pm?hl=en

Maybe you made more than 1ooo requests per 1oo seconds.

Currently your code makes as many parallel requests in a split second as long your array is. I would rather use `async - await` with `for - in` or `for - of` and `await` each request and convert it into a series instead of parallel requests or with a similar approach it is possible to create a request pool and send for example 1o parallel requests at once and send the next one only after a request opportunity frees up in the pool.